# Javascript / Node.js и контекст функций

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, асинхронность

Добрый день. Есть следующий код. (упрощен)

```
function first_func(somedata) {
  if (somedata == true) {
    let data = {};

    mysql.query('SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = 1', function(err, results, fields) {
      data['id'] = results[0].id;
      data['name'] = results[0].name;
    });

    console.log(data); // {}
  }
}

first_func(true);
```

Не могу добавить данные в data. При этом я понял что либо теряется контекст, либо вызов console.log идет до записи данных. Пробовал делать стрелочную функцию (err, results,fields) => { ... }, результат тот же.

Comment: Контекст ни при чем (можно проверить сделав вывод данных внутри колбека), код асинхронный, по этому `console.log()` отрабатывает раньше, чем в объект добавляются данные.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в от что mysql.query асинхронная функция по ее окончанию вызывается callback в то время когда вызовится callback 
уже отработает console.log(data);

проще говоря код выполняется последовательно но не ожидает но не ожидает окончания работы mysql.query

Как вариант можно mysql.query завернуть в promise и использовать async/await, ну или более изощренные способы.

Comment: Как вариант,  мне кажется, больше подходит, если  `console.log` поместить внутрь каллбэка функции `mysql.query`

Comment: @Дмытрык смотря что человеку надо, если в место console.log return то нет, если просто обработка данных то может быть.